Sporadic Segfault with Sanitizer on empty main
I have issues with a (simple) c++ application, in case  the sanitizer is enabled. It runs (well /wo). The issue is not, that it claims errors in code. The whole thing terminates with a segfault and I started digging.
Now, at the very bottom, I have the following setup:
On Ubuntu 22.04 with g++-11.4 I compiled a !on-liner!
int main( int argc, char** argv ) { return 0; }

with g++-11 -std=gnu++14 -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=leak -fsanitize=undefined -fstack-protector-all main.cpp
Then: I executed the application several times and once in a while it ends like this:
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL

with an infinit loop.
Any ideas to get further in investigations?
Update 1
When I exclude address sanitizer and keeping only leak I get seg fault sometimes.
g++-11 -std=gnu++14 -fsanitize=leak main.cpp
[1]    119683 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out
Side note: This happens on more than one machine. (I hoped to be a victim of a hw failure :-P )
Update 2
Tried with Ubuntu 24.04:
--> no issues
Tried with Ubuntu 18.04:
root@4c1dfbe5b382:/# g++-11 -std=gnu++14 -fsanitize=address main.cpp 
root@4c1dfbe5b382:/# ./a.out 
root@4c1dfbe5b382:/# ./a.out 
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
Segmentation fault (core dumped)


Have you tried running with a debugger?

yes. For strange reasons, it does not pop up while running on gdb. I am guessing that it has something to do with an initialization at load.

Seems like perhaps a race condition (i.e. a bug) in the GCC. Have you checked their bugtracker?

Not all sanitizers support being enabled at the same time. Have you verified that -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=leak -fsanitize=undefined is a valid combination?

As one can see at Update 2. It crashes even if only -fsanitize=address or like at Update 1 only -fsanitize=leak ist set.
I've checked the bugtracker. There are some bugs which might address the topic, but i am not sure, because I have no backtrace to compare

can't reproduce under WSL with an AMD CPU

we tried it on docker ubuntu 18.04, 22.04 and 24.04 with the results posted above.
